# Magento 2.2.5 Add product custom fields in view page

Tags: custom-options, product-view, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I need to achieve the following:
In product detail(view) page, I need to add the mandatory `from date`, `to date` and `Comments` fields. That should be added in the order Details and also in the custom table. How to achieve this.

Comment: You can use additional fields of magento2 when adding to cart. And in view page you can override the addtocart.phtml and add your fields according to your requirement.